# Why don't Java's number classes extend each other?

Tags: java, inheritance, numbers

In Java, why don't the built-in number classes extend each other? Shouldn't Long extend Integer which extends Short which extends Byte, and Double extend Float?

In general, inheritance is often used when there's an "is a" relationship. So is every Integer a Long? I think so.

The only possible explanation I can think of is that overflow won't be handled correctly. For example, `(byte)100 + (byte)100` is `-112`, whereas `(short)100 + (short)100` is `200`. However, it seems that there should be a better reason than preserving buggy behavior.

Comment: `So is every Integer a Long?` - no, `long` is twice as large in memory.

Comment: @August But that's an implementation detail, which is of course allowed be different.

Comment: Based on the [substitutability principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle), your relationships are backwards. `Integer` should extend `Long` since you can always provide an `Integer` when asked for a `Long`, but not the other way around since some `Long` values are not valid `Integer` values.

Comment: They don't really need to. The smaller primitives have widening conversions to the larger.

Comment: The built-in number classes mirror the primitive types. There's no inheritance relation between primitive types, so there's no inheritance relation between the primitive wrapper classes.

Comment: What if feels like to me, based on your argument, is that there should be types in between, such as `IntegralNumber` and `FloatingPointNumber`, which `Integer`, `Long`, `Short`, etc; and `Float` and `Double` inherit from. It doesn't really make sense for an `Integer` to inherit from a `Long`, since integers aren't longs. But this method doesn't really add anything useful to the mix; there isn't really that much more information given by having `IntegralNumber`s and `FloationPointNumber`s

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You question can really be approached in two different ways:

If we are talking about primitives, then you have the relationship backwards.

But, if you are asking about the `Integer`, `Double`, `Long`, etc. classes, then there is a relationship between all the numbers.

It's important to point out that numbers as objects in Java stem from a common `Number` class found [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Number.html). It doesn't make much sense to break them down in the hierarchy like how you described because the methods between all the numbers are essentially the same, despite the varying sizes in memory they take up.

**In short, hierarchies in Java are defined by the relationships (typically methods) that classes share, not the size they take up in memory.**

Answer (score 3):

Because there is nothing to inherit. Each of the types listed are their own separate entity. Inheritance can't be used to "extend" an 8-bit value to a 32-bit one, for example. Anything that they do have in common is inherited from `java.lang.Number`.

Answer (score 3):

You might consider using inheritance whenever there's an "is a" relationship between two classes - you might have a banking system with classes called `Account` and `SavingsAccount` - and a savings account is an account.  Effectively, it means that any object of the subclass also belongs to the superclass.

But there's no such relationship between `Integer` (32-bit integer) and `Long` (64-bit integer).  A 32-bit integer IS NOT A 64-bit integer; and a 64-bit integer IS NOT A 32-bit integer.  So to suggest that there's an inheritance relationship between the `Integer` class and the `Long` class makes no sense.